# responsive design - image and text together

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I am designing a responsive website and i am stuck in making this part as responsive.

attached is the image where red round is the image acting as buttons and field below that image is used as input text to enter the data. now how do i make this responsive, so that both image and text resize in proportion. 
I tried ImageMaps plugin, but what i understood is that this plugin is good for image resizing, not for image and textfield as a whole.

i also tried to place text over the image, but still the image gets responsive with ImageMaps but not not textfield.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPO0f.png

The codes Tried:

```
<img id="img-htp" class="img-center img-responsive img-margin" width="2419" height="897" src="{res}images/home1.jpg" usemap="#image-maps" alt="Home Figure">
    <map name="image-maps" id="image-maps">
        <area  alt="language" title="Language" href="http://www.google.ca" shape="rect" coords="0,317,267,587" style="outline:none;" target="_self"/>
        <area  alt="sign me in" title="Sign me in" href="login" shape="rect" coords="555,314,821,584" style="outline:none;" target="_self"/>
        <area  alt="create future account" title="Create future account" href="login/registeration" shape="rect" coords="2161,319,2419,586" style="outline:none;" target="_self"/>
    </map>
```

Script Used:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
});
```

Comment: post what you tried .

Answer (score 0):

You would likely be best served by a js library.

[FittextJS](http://fittextjs.com/) is one that allows text to scale. In general text doesn't scale responsively.

Comment: Hi Frank, it didn't helped.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle? maybe I am not understanding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What Frank said or you could use the `vw` & `vh` units in css3

`vw` stand for viewport width percentage.

If you have `font-size:10vw;` your font size will be 10 percent of the screen width.

Here's a demo: http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/